# All fuelsdk archives archived, any alternate way to query/load data extensions in Python?

Tags: dataextensions, fuel-sdk, python

About a week ago, all the FuelSDK archives were archived (under https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud).

Question: Does anyone know of a forthcoming replacement? And is there an expectation the SOAP api underlying them is going to have breaking changes in near future?

For python, there is a fork at https://github.com/seahawks8/FuelSDK-Python which I haven't tried yet.  I've been told the original won't load in python 3.10+ but still to verify.

Comment: I started with making a config file and then doing simple REST and SOAP API calls.  Once you get a few successful patterns, you can turn it into whatever.  If you're expecting to build something that works for bulk data operations, you'll be disappointed.

Comment: Thank you @AdamSpriggs.  I need to read from  and load data into existing Marketing Cloud "Data Extensions."  It doesn't look to me like REST is api is relevant to that.  I am guessing mine is about as easy a use case as anyone will ever have, but I'm not at all familiar with SOAP.  Do you know of any sample code, or are you able to post a gist?  I'm looking around at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/overview, and not getting any traction.

Comment: I'd suggest looking over the Postman collection that Salesforce provides for SFMC: https://www.postman.com/salesforce-developers/workspace/salesforce-developers/collection/14448118-2835a976-010c-4548-92f8-f42c0382758e?action=share&creator=407776

Comment: Thanks, I will look it over and post new question if I get stuck on it.  Meanwhile I'll leave this unanswered; still wondering if SalesForce is planning to retired SOAP APIs/create REST endpoints for operations on Data Extensions.